# How can I combine Angular 9 frontend with ASP.NET 4.7 API backend in one solution file?

Tags: asp.net, .net, angular, asp.net-web-api, hosting

I have made an angular 9 app separately using angular CLI. Alongside I have a ASP. NET 4.7.2 web application (WEB API to be accurate) for api calls to be made from  front-end (ng). How can I merge both of them in single solution file so that I can host the full application on a Windows shared hosting server?
Two queries:

1. How to merge them in single solution file?
2. How to make final hosting package which I will upload on the plesk file maneger of my shared server?

*PS: Please don't link answers for .NET CORE. I have enough of them already.*

More info if needed: angular running on port 4200 currently and API at 3000.

Comment: Any way  I found the solution, Will write detail solution soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to change launch path on .NET Framework project and index.html

1.Create Empty .NET Framework
[image]

2.Create Angular Project in .NET Frame work project
For example:angular-sample project. and this project output files to dist folder.
[image]

3.Set index.html in Angular Project
[image]

4.Change base tag in src/index.html
`<base href="/angular-sample/dist/angular-sample/">`

5.Let's Ctrl + F5.